# Interpretation of composition operator when applying a function to the output of another function

Tags: function-and-relation-composition, chain-rule

Refreshing my calculus skills a bit, I reviewed the chain rule:

[image]

I wondered if the composition operation $\circ$ in $g \circ f(x)$ could actually also be written as $g(f(x))$ as this would resemble how one might think about such an operation from a (functional) programming perspective.

### Disclaimer

My background is in Software Engineering combined with **Applied** Statistical Analysis within the context of a degree in Business Administration - so unfortunately never had heavy formal training on theoretical Math. Thus apologies if I might sometimes not use the correct technical terms and/or express things a bit "unmathy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wondered if the composition operation $\circ$ in $g \circ f(x)$ could actually also be written as $g(f(x))$ as this would resemble how one might think about such an operation from a (functional) programming perspective.

Yup; in fact, that's often how function composition is introduced (having a function take another function as its input). As to which convention - $(g \circ f)(x)$ or $g(f(x))$ - to use in your own work, both are fairly accepted notations. Just be sure to remember that, in the former, the composition is *usually* right-to-left, or inward-out in the latter notation.

As a simple example to verify this for clarity, let $g(x) = \cos(x)$ and $f(x) = x^2$. Then $(g\circ f)(x) = g(f(x)) = \cos(x^2)$.

Comment: Perfect explanation, thanks a lot :-)